# How to select objects from a list that has a property that matches an item in another list?

Tags: linq, list, windows-phone-7

Hard question to understand perhaps, but let me explain. I have a `List` of `Channel`-objects, that all have a `ChannelId` property (`int`). I also have a different `List` (`int`) - `SelectedChannelIds`, that contains a subset of the `ChannelId`-s.

I want to select (through `LINQ`?) all the `Channel`-objects that has a `ChannelId`-property matching one in the second `List`.

in other words, I have the following structure:

```
public class Lists
{
    public List<Channel> AllChannels = ChannelController.GetAllChannels();
    public List<int> SelectedChannelIds = ChannelController.GetSelectedChannels();

    public List<Channel> SelectedChannels; // = ?????
}

public class Channel
{
    // ...
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Any ideas on what that LINQ query would look like? Or is there a more effective way? I'm coding for the Windows Phone 7, fyi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`List.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) in a `Where` clause:

```
public Lists()
{
    SelectedChannels = AllChannels
        .Where(channel => SelectedChannelIds.Contains(channel.ChannelId))
        .ToList();
}
```

Note that it would be more efficient if you used a `HashSet<int>` instead of a `List<int>` for the `SelectedChannelIds`. Changing to a `HashSet` will improve the performance from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n), though if your list is always quite small this may not be a significant issue.

Comment: Mark - thanks for a great and informative answer. My list will never be more than 140, and usually around 40. Will it still be a performance gain here?

Answer (score 1):

```
SelectedChannels = new List<Channel>(AllChannels.Where(c => SelectedChannelIds.Contains(c.ChannelId)));
```